# Difference between HBoxLayout and VBoxLayout in Qt

Tags: qt, layout

I was just reading sample codes for layout in Qt, and I found the following two lines for Hboxlayout and VBoxlayout,

```
    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
    QHBoxLayout *hbox = new QHBoxLayout(this);
```

I don't understand the difference, why there is a this pointer send as parameter in the latter one, and not in the first one?

What is the this pointer actually referring to?

Comment: The difference is unrelated to H/VBoxLayout, you could see the same difference between any QObject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why there is a this pointer send as parameter in the latter one, and not in the first one?

Both constructors exist, see [QHBoxLayout](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qhboxlayout.html) and [QVBoxLayout](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qvboxlayout.html).

> What is the this pointer actually referring to?

When calling the variant which takes a pointer, this pointer (`this` in your case) takes ownership of the new object, which means that it also deletes it when it is itself deleted.

Otherwise, you need to take care of deleting the object yourself (or set the parent at a later point). 
In case of the box layouts, as mentioned in the documentation linked above, you need to add the layout to another layout in this case.

As @Mat mentioned, this is a general concept in Qt, see also [QObject::Qbject(QObject* parent = 0)](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qobject.html#QObject).